# Why did Ikkaku appear as Urahara during his fight with Ichigo?

Tags: bleach

During the fight between Ichigo Kurosaki and Ikkaku Madarame in episode 27 of the Bleach anime, Ikkaku briefly appears as Kisuke Urahara while he is running towards Ichigo. This can be seen in the image below, but he disappears mere seconds later. But why can we see Urahara here? Is this in the manga as well?

> I understand that Urahara is a former division captain of the Gotei 13, but this doesn't explain why he appears. Besides, Ikkaku belongs to the 11th Division, while Urahara belonged to the 12th.

[image: Ikkaku Madarame is running towards the camera. Kisuke Urahara appears beside him.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it backwards here.

Around that point in the anime, Ichigo is fighting *Ikakku*.  He's recalling the training he did with Urahara, which is why this is being overlayed.

Comment: Okay, Ichigo recalling his training makes sense, but I don't understand the first part of your answer. What do you mean by "you've got it backwards here"?

Comment: You're saying "Ikakku briefly appears".  It really should be "Kisuke briefly appears".